# CGDisplayCreateImage doesn't have cursor

Tags: swift, image, cocoa, screenshot

I'm taking a screen shot of the screen using:

```
let image = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID())
```

However, `image` doesn't have a cursor. Is there any way to include a cursor in `image`?

I saw a bunch of other questions saying that `CGDisplayCreateImage` only included the wallpaper, and the fix was to enable some permissions/signing locally. However, I already have all of those things checked. It's just the cursor isn't showing.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685854/screen-capture-using-objective-c-for-mac

Comment: You have to put it in the screenshot for yourself.